# Strip attributes in HTML tag span

Tags: php, parsing, attributes, strip-tags, dom

I'm fetching data through CURL request and while parsing the HTML I'm some spans having attributes are not being parsed neatly.

Snippet of HTML code

```
<div class="ftlt" style="width:250px;">
    <div class="tdiv"><span class="prop_price_img"></span><span class="property_price">PROPERTY_PRICE</span></div>
    <p class="adPrice">AREA</p>
    <h4>
      <p style="float:left;width:251px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;padding:2px 10px 10px 0px;"><a href="some link" title="title">TITLE</a>,
                  <span style="color:#666;"> CITY_NAME.</span> 

                <a title="title, Sale" style="color:#3266CC;font-size:12px;text-decoration:underline;">View on map</a></p>
    </h4>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;color:#666;">
           Premium
          </p>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
```

I have to access the CITY_NAME element neatly.
I have been able to fetch that node through HTML DOM as

```
$spans = $html->find(div.ftlt span);
$city_value=strip_tags($spans[2]);
```

This `$city_value` is getting morphed.
I've tried removeAttribute method.Maybe I'm not doing it properly.

If regex can be applied, I want to know how?

Answer (score 0):

```
$spans = $html->find(div.ftlt span);
$city_value=$spans[2]->nodeValue;
```

Why don't you use [nodeValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)?

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the incoming HTML?

Comment: You can try utf8_decode() your curl_exec... Or if the encoding isn't utf8 you can use iconv to change the encoding

Comment: Doesn't work.I think the problem is with the attributes that are after the span.